# What does this mean? World consume 14 trillion watts of power

Tags: energy, time, power

I am not very clear about this statement. Does that mean in every second we are consuming that much energy?

Comment: What's the source of this claim?

Comment: No, the statement means (whether it is true or false doesn't matter) that every second the world consumes 14 trillion *Joules of energy*. One watt is one Joule per second. For example, on a monthly electricity bill, there will be a monthly usage listed in kilowatt hours, which is 1000 x 3600 Joules or 1000 x 3600 watt-seconds.

Comment: @stafusa it doesn't matter. The OP is not asking about the validity of the claim, it's a question about how the units of energy versus power work. There's no need for the OP to cite the source in this case, or to badger a new user with a distracting question.

Comment: @uhoh That's your interpretation of OP's question. While I agree on the need to clarify their energy/power confusion, they can very well be amazed at how large the number is. There's no need to badger an old member with unfounded criticism. :-P

Comment: @stafusa I just wanted to know in every second are we consuming that much energy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about parsing a statement about energy usage and not physics concepts.

Answer (score 3):

A watt is a unit of *power*, not energy. Power is energy *per unit time*. Every second we use on average 14 trillion *joules* of energy. A joule per second is a watt.

By the way, when you divide 14 trillion watts by the roughly 7 billion humans on Earth, each human uses about 2,000 watts as a continuous average. This is an easily grasped number. (For example, one bright pre-LED light bulb continuously consumed 100 watts.)

Comment: And then consider those who don't have any access to electricity to then think about those who make up that difference...